# Flask run a bash ffmpeg command not returning and not executing

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Python and to Flask as well.

I'm trying to run a esay ffmpeg command which should create a file named `{name}.mp4.meta` duration, so I did:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import make_response

import sys
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

root_folder = "~/myfolder/"

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)

@app.route('/jolly/1.0/meta/<path:video>')
def jolly_metadata(video):
    #video = request.form.get("video")
    cmd = 'ffprobe -i '+root_folder+video+' -show_entries format=duration -sexagesimal -v quiet -print_format json > '+root_folder+video+'.meta'
    dati = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate()
    return "ok"+dati[0]
```

This returns no error, no output and the file is not created. If I run the same command in my shell (and Flask shell too) all works good.

I wanted to get the `video` name from POST request but first I need to get this working.

Comment: In Python 3.6+, use `subprocess.run()`. In earlier versions, use `subprocess.check_output()`. You want to avoid raw `Popen()` unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Tangentially, you also watn to avoid `shell=True` whenever you can. This is obviously one of those situations; you aren't using any shell features except splitting the command line on whitespace, which you can trivially do yourself.